# Creating multiple columns from a csv one row file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I'm struggling with separating the data from the one and only row I have in a CSV file. While the file has multiple columns the information is on one row and therefore looks like this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 ... |Column 628
Seconds  |   X1     |  X2          |Seconds
```

I just want each 'Seconds' instance to be in the same column as well as each instance of X and Y, so I want the end product to look like this:

```
Column one   Column 2 Column 3

Seconds      x         y  
Seconds      x         y     
Seconds      x         y
```

So far, I've tried using values.reshape to try and structure the data at least a bit but I couldn't find anything on how to extract specific values and put them into new columns. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question is not exactly clear. Please provide a trimmed & sanitized exact example of the source data next time.

From what I understood you have a single-line csv file with repeating instances of `seconds, x, y`. If this is the case then it's reasonably easy to split this and then process the resulting list.

**input csv**

```
seconds1, x1, y1, seconds2, x2, y2, seconds3, x3, y3, seconds4, x4, y4, seconds5, x5, y5
```

**code**

You might need to change the delimiter to split on.

```py
import pandas as pd

delimiter = ','
with open("69306802.csv") as infile:
    input_data = infile.read().strip("\n").split(delimiter)


df = pd.DataFrame({
        "seconds": input_data[::3],
        "x": input_data[1::3],
        "y": input_data[2::3]
    })
print(df)
```

**output**

```
     seconds    x    y
0   seconds1   x1   y1
1   seconds2   x2   y2
2   seconds3   x3   y3
3   seconds4   x4   y4
4   seconds5   x5   y5
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what does the [::3] represent in this case?

Comment: That's list slicing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/9267296) for details.

Comment: The third variable is step. In this case you basically create a new list for each third element of the original list starting at element 0. The other 2 start at index 1 and 2 respectively.